# How to make Mathematica give the output differently?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

When you compute the Fourier transform

```
FourierTransform[Sqrt[2/π] 1/(1 + λ^2), λ, p]
```

Mathematica gives the output

```
E^-Abs[p]
```

But when you compute

```
FullSimplify[FourierTransform[Sqrt[2/π] c/(c^2 + λ^2), λ, p],Assumptions -> {c > 0}]
```

Mathematica gives

```
E^(c p) HeavisideTheta[-p] + E^(-c p) HeavisideTheta[p]
```

How do I instead make it give the answer as

```
E^(-c Abs[p])
```

Comment: Please write a more-informative title.  Yours could apply to almost any problem.